# Regex match everything but last four digits

Tags: regex

I need a regex match for everything in a string except the last sequence of four digits.

```
abc12345 => abc1
abc1234abc => abcabc
abc123.45678abc => abc123.4abc
1234abc => abc
12345abc => 1abc
```

I have tried lots and lots of things. The closest I got is with

```
.*[^(\d{4})]
```

but when there are characters behind the last secquence of four this fails.

Comment: What programing language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can glue together parts of regular expression is by utilizing power of back-references. You can learn more about back references [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

This code solves your problem and you can see regular expression demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fFIMPf/1):

```
([a-z0-9.]*)\d{4}([a-z0-9]+)
```

Basically whenever you put something into normal brackets `()` that counts as back-reference, `([a-z0-9.]*)` this would be first back-reference, `([a-z0-9]+)` this would be second. If you for example wanted to have this regex:

```
([a-z0-9.]*)([a-z0-9.]*)
```

You could use back-reference to that bracket:

```
([a-z0-9.]*)\1
```

Of course, this be could solved simply with:

```
([a-z0-9.]*){2}
```

but in this case`{2}` has to go right after regex, opposite to back references, after they've being defined, they can be used anywhere. For example:

```
([a-z0-9.]*) Continuation of regular expression \1
```

From your question it is not clear in what programming language you are working. However, most programing languages support back-references. What you want to do is create regex like this, and then access first and third back reference, concatenate them and extract text.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*\d*)(\d{4})(.*)
```

This will allow you to combine 1st and 3rd match.

[Online Regular Expressions](https://regex101.com/)